# Twitter Bootstrap Rails is loading bootswatch.less before variables.less 3.0

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I upgraded my app from Bootstrap 2.3.2 to 3.0.  I got it working with a modified bootstrap.css.  When I want to use bootswatch.less and variables.less I get an error where:

```
variable @navbar-default-bg is undefined
```

But that variable is defined in the variables.less file. Here is my import from my bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less file:

```
@import "bootswatch/variables";
@import "bootswatch/bootswatch";
```

It is as if it is loading the less files in alphabetical order and not as the import implies.

I tried renaming variables.less to avariables.less and it still isn't getting imported.

Note:  The app blows up unless I remove the bootswatch.less file from the app.  It is like all the variables being called in the bootswatch.less file which are defined in variables.less are not being recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used the complete name of the import-file and after that it worked for me.

```
@import "bootswatch/variables.less";
@import "bootswatch/bootswatch.less";
```

My problem was that I named my files `xxx.css.less` and I imported `xxx.css`. Less searching then after a real css-file, maybe this changes help you too.

Comment: I had tried that as well ( noted in original post), and to this day have settled for modifying the template bootstrap.css

Comment: Can you please post your ```bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less``` file (maybe on gist)?